# Collapse block of text to specific amount of lines

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented a js plugin called readmore.js from http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/ which I'm using to collapse a large amount of text as you can see on http://gordonsbay.hashfff.com/accommodation/beachfront-apartment-overlooking-the-bay/

I want to only display the first 10 lines of text when the block is collapsed. The line-height is set 1.3. I assumed that setting the block to 13em (1.3 * 10) would do the trick but unfortunately not as it is cutting the last line in half.

I'm not looking for someone to help me go about this the right way.

**HTML**

```
<section class="accomm-info" data-readmore="" aria-expanded="false" id="rmjs-1" style="max-height: none; height: 240px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <p><strong>Minimum stay 3&nbsp;nights</strong></p>
                    <p>This lovely ground floor self catering apartment or similar has magnificent uninterrupted views looking across False Bay, with Table Mountain in the distance.&nbsp;The apartment block is situated in the heart of the old village across the road from the beach.&nbsp;It is within walking distance of restaurants, shops &nbsp;and pubs.</p>
                    <p>1 x queen bed,&nbsp;2 x &nbsp;single beds. 1 x double sleeper couch</p>
                    <p>Main en suite – bath and toilet</p>
                    <p>2nd bathroom – shower and toilet</p>
                    <p>There is a built in braai on the ground level overlooking the sea.</p>
                    <p>Wi-fi is for your own account.</p>
                    <p>Exit fee of R200.00</p>
                     p>* Accommodation</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.accomm-info {
  max-height: none;
  height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: each paragraph in your block has a margin-bottom of 10px. You probably didn't have accounted that in.

Comment: set `height:255px` ?

Comment: Chance `.accom-info`'s `height` to `220px` and see if it fits.

Comment: I ended up using the inspector to check the height of the <p> tags and multiply by 10 which worked for me.